# Where should I store meta data, and how should I read it?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to add some meta-data to a class, for example

```
@SomeMetaInfo("hello")
export class SomeData {
  public name: string;
  public age: number;
}
```

Inside my `SomeMetaInfo` decorator where would I store the value "Hello"? This is what I have tried so far

```
function SomeMetaInfo(someValue: string) {
  return (target: Function) => {
    target.prototype["SomeMetaInfo:someValue"] = someValue;
  }
}
```

But is this really the place I should store the value? And how should I read the value back?

Comment: I wonder if there's a way you could integrate mixins here? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html.

Comment: I've never done that sort of thing in Angular, seems like the right 'use case' though.  Otherwise, I think what you've done here is fine.  Maybe make a key just for the metadata bucket and put all metadata in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the recommended approach is to use the [reflect-metadata](https://github.com/rbuckton/reflect-metadata) module.